# Qt C++ operator == overload Qlist not called

Tags: c++, qt

My operator == is not beeing called when i use QList or QHashMap

here is my code :

```
class Node
{
    QString     _state;
    Node*       _parent;
    // for ID generation purpose
    static int  _seqNumber;
    int         _id;
public:
    Node();
    inline bool operator== (const Node &node) const
    {
         return ( _id == node._id  );
    }
 }
```

Now if i use QHash for example :

```
    QHash<Node*, double> hashMap* = new QHash<Node*, double>();
    Node* node = new Node();

    hashMap->insert(node, 500);

    // value is never found, because operator== is not being called
    double value = hashMap->value(node);
```

I can't get value or compare is node exists in the map because operator== is not called !!

If you can help i would apreciate that.

Comment: ... also, I think using Qt when you barely handle C++ correctly is too much for now. My honest recommendation is to learn more C++ before attempting to fly.

Comment: Don’t create container instances such as QHash on the heap, use the stack.

Answer (score 5):

This is [expected behaviour](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qhash.html#details). You are using `Node*` as your key-type, but there is no special `operator==(Node*,Node*)` defined.

What you seem to intend is `Node`.

Answer (score 0):

The Hash key is a pointer(`Node*`) not a `Node` object. so the map or hash is comparing pointers in there. Thus, there's really no need to your `operator==`.

And you cannot ask compiler to use your function to compare two pointers. because a pointer is a primitive type just like an `int`. you cannot overload `operator==` to compare two `int`s.

So, I think the solution, could be to use your object as hash key like this:

```
QHash<Node, double> //[1]
```

or just use pointer and leave the comparison to pointer comparisons.

[1] But then, you'd have to provide a hash function for the `QHash` to work as well.

Comment: Thank you, but what do you mean by " you'd have to provide a hash function for the QHash ?

Comment: Since you said QHash, I assume you are using [Qt's QHash class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html). Have you checked the documents? _"A QHash's key type has additional requirements other than being an assignable data type: it must provide operator==(), and there must also be a qHash() function in the type's namespace that returns a hash value for an argument of the key's type."_ So you have to write a `uint qHash(Node)` function which accepts your key type, and returns a `uint` which is the hash value it's going to use.

Comment: Okay thank you, i ll try implementing the qHash function

Comment: You're welcome. If your id is unique you might be able to use the available qHash for int. And If it answers your question, please mark it as accepted too.